# Счетчик дней В Андроид

Tags: java, android

Вопрос:

Как сделать чтобы пользователь установил текущую или какую нибудь дату, и считать сколько дней прошло с указанной даты?

Буду рад примерам или советам в какую сторону копать!

Comment: Даете пользователю возможность ввести дату либо берете текущую. Сохраняете в shared preferences как вариант. В нужный момент из текущей даты вычитаете сохраненную получаете свой результат.

Comment: Спасибо. Пошёл пробовать!
(А как вычитать даты?)

Comment: ниже расписали уже)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ваша активность:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    .....


}
```

добавляем переменную, которая отображает выбранную дату:

```
 Calendar dateAndTime=Calendar.getInstance();
```

на какое-то действие выводим диалог выбора даты:

```
new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, d,
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                .show();
```

дальше добавляем обработчик выбора даты:

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            
        }
    };
```

дальше получаем разницу в днях между двумя датами `Calendar.getInstance()` и `dateAndTime`:

```
long diff = dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

float dayCount = (float) diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976989/java-get-days-between-two-dates) можно почитать про получение разницы во времени а тут есть [туториал](https://metanit.com/java/android/18.1.php) по работе с селекторами даты и времени